# Iterate a List<string> 12 by 12 and get the items

Tags: c#, list, model, vsto

I have a generic list of strings, but I know from 12 to 12 items I have a Record. I Also have a Model that want to populate.

My primary code

```
for (int r = 2; r <= rows; r++)
{
    for (int c = 3; c <= cols; c++)
    {
        try
        {
            list.Add(usedRange.Cells[r, c].Value2.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}

foreach (string item in list)
{

}
```

So in foreach (string item in list) I know 12 the 24 then 36 my record is there

The problem is this peace of code

```
foreach (string item in list)
{
  p.LastName = item
}
```

I need a `for` in order to populate my Model with all 12 items, I'm stuck

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem that you are having is that in that foreach you are doing a iteration for all items and you only want item 12, item 24 and item 36?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have your list in chunks of 12 elements, you can use the `Chunk` Linq extension which is new in C# 10. An equivalent is available in the library [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) if you don't use C# 10, it has a different name: [Batch](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#batch).

```cs
// Creating a sample list of dummy elements
// There will be 100 strings from "0" to "99".
var MyList = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(i => $"{i}");

// Creating a list of chunks containing 12 elements
var ChunkedElements = MyList
    .Chunk(12);

// Using the chunked list.
foreach (var chunk in ChunkedElements)
{
    // Do what you want with the 12 elements
    Console.WriteLine("New Chunk");
    foreach(var e in chunk)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
New Chunk
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
New Chunk
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
New Chunk
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
New Chunk
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
New Chunk
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
New Chunk
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
New Chunk
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
New Chunk
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
New Chunk
96
97
98
99
```

If you only want every 12th element, here is a Linq alternative to the classical for loops. It is not better or worst, but can be useful depending on the context.

```cs
// Creating a sample list of dummy elements
// There will be 100 strings from "0" to "99".
var MyList = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(i => $"{i}");

// Filtering the list to get only the 12th elements
var FilteredElements = MyList
    .Where((e, i) => i % 12 == 0);

// Using the filtered list
foreach (var e in FilteredElements)
{
    // Here do what you want with each element.
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Output:

```
0
12
24
36
48
60
72
84
96
```

Explanation:

`.Where((e, i) => i % 12 == 0)` is where the work is done. The linq extension method `Where` has an overload that takes as argument a Func<TSource, Int32, bool>. See [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__). The second parameter is the index of the element of the collection.

So `.Where((e, i) => i % 12 == 0)` keeps only the elements of the collection for which the index `i` is divisible by 12 (`i % 12 == 0`). Hence the result containing only multiples of 12.

Comment: Hi, I need to add positions to the model, so in each ```foreach (var e in filteredElements)``` is only passed one value, I need this ```foreach (var e in filteredElements){p.LastName = e; p.FirstName = e;```

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if I understand your needs correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get item each 12 elements with a `for` by index like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i+=12)
    var p.LastName = list[i];
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is 12+ is not incremented, always from 0 to 12

Answer (score 1):

For now is like this but I'll change it to a smother approach.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i += 13)
{
    p.Add(new Participants()
    {
        LastName = list[0+i],
        FirstName = list[1 + i],
        AddressType = list[2 + i],
        Email = list[3 + i],
        Company = list[4 + i],
        Phone = list[5 + i],
        Street = list[6 + i],
        ZipCode = list[7 + i],
        City = list[8 + i],
        Country = list[9 + i],
        Percent = list[10 + i],
        Points = list[11 + i],
        Passed = list[12 + i],
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice! Be careful because this `for` can `throw` an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. You are trying to access `list[12+i]`. Condition `i < list.Count` should be changed to something like `i < list.Count - 12`. So you will avoid this exception.